# Access property in ViewModel from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have ViewModel with property for displaying notification:

```
  public class NotificationViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    private string errorText;
    public string ErrorText
    {
      get => this.errorText;
      set
      {
        this.errorText = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }
```

Then in MainViewModel.cs I have following command that should display notification in case there is some error:

```
public NotificationViewModel NotificationViewModel { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel()
{

}

private async Task AddProjectToDatabase()
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ProjectNumber))
  {
    // some other code here
  }
  else
  {
    NotificationDialog view = new NotificationDialog
    {
      DataContext = new NotificationViewModel()
    };

    this.NotificationViewModel.ErrorText = "Select project number first!";
    object result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "MainDialogHost", this.ExtendedOpenedEventHandler, this.ExtendedNotificationClosingEventHandler);
  }
}
```

I have tried to:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
  this.NotificationViewModel = new NotificationViewModel();
}
```

However in this case I have no text displayed, as there is now new instance of NotificationViewModel is initialized. I have probably to somehow inject existing instance into MainViewModel.cs ? How I can do that? If there is something missing to privide an answer, please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `NotificationViewModel` property to `DataContext` of `NotificationDialog`.

```
private async Task AddProjectToDatabase()
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ProjectNumber))
  {
    // some other code here
  }
  else
  {
    NotificationDialog view = new NotificationDialog
    {
      DataContext = this.NotificationViewModel
    };

    this.NotificationViewModel.ErrorText = "Select project number first!";
    object result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "MainDialogHost", this.ExtendedOpenedEventHandler, this.ExtendedNotificationClosingEventHandler);
  }
}
```